# Audit logs for RDS MySQL not appearing in CloudWatch

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I've been trying to get a MySQL instance on Amazon's RDS to send logs to CloudWatch: in particular, both error logs and audit logs.

Error logs work fine, they're appearing in CloudWatch, no issues at all. For audit logs, I know I need to have the MariaDB Audit Plugin enabled - so, I've added it to an option group, and added that option group to the MySQL instance. I've also restarted the instance (which is apparently not needed, but I figure it was worth trying). I've also connected to the MySQL database a few times since enabling this about 24 hours ago.

Here are the settings I've attached to the `MARIADB_AUDIT_PLUGIN` option (I've only customised the events, everything else are the default values):

[image: MARIADB_AUDIT_PLUGIN options]

But: there is no log group, and there is also no mention of the audit file in the list of log files for the RDS instance. Any thoughts on what else I can try to debug this?

Also, when I connect to the database and check on the known plugins via `SELECT plugin_name from information_schema.plugins`, the MariaDB Audit Plugin is not listed. Should it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out two of the settings are required (and don't fall back to [the documented defaults](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MySQL.Options.AuditPlugin.html#Appendix.MySQL.Options.AuditPlugin.Options)): `SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATIONS` and `SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATE_SIZE`. Once these are explicitly set in my options group, I've found that the log file appears in the RDS instance's console page, *and* they flow through to CloudWatch as well.