# AWS RDS Slow Query, General, and Audit logs have disappeared. Enhanced Monitoring cannot be turned on

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I had AWS RDS enhanced monitoring turned on in our Production and UAT RDS databases. These are connected to an ERP instance.

I went to look for slow queries while debugging a user issue, and ***the Audit, General, and Slow Query logs have disappeared.***

They were and are enabled. They used to be in CloudWatch. Not a one left, even though we > 1 year retention.

If I go through the control panel and click on the hyperlink from "Published Logs" CloudWatch says

```
There was an error filtering log events
The specified log group does not exist
```

[image]

The error logs do exist, and do not show any logging errors.

I also tried turning the other logs off, letting settings persist, then turning them on. The other logs (slow SQL, etc) still don't exist.

These logs for production are business critical - I mean, if your audit log suddenly disappears, it's hard to build alerts, right? I can't believe there isn't even an error about these logs disappearing.

I did see that "Enhanced Monitoring" was turned off, so I turned it on, and got this:

> Amazon RDS has been unable to configure enhanced monitoring on your instance: uat and this feature has been disabled.This is likely due to the rds-monitoring-role not being present and configured correctly in your account. Please refer to the troubleshooting section in the Amazon RDS documentation for further details.

The role does exist and hasn't changed since 2019.

rds-monitoring-role, Trust Relationships:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "monitoring.rds.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

One other thing: I did install DataDog's AWS integration CloudWatch routine about two weeks ago. That might be roughly when all the logs disappeared, but I think that's more coincidental, or I'd open a ticket with them. I deleted their CloudWatch stack, and the logs have not come back.

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/925376/audit-logs-for-rds-mysql-not-appearing-in-cloudwatch) mentions log parameters, but I checked and ours haven't changed.

Comment: I've finally opened a support ticket, but AWS is also flummoxed. AWS Cloudwatch support is now talking to AWS RDS support.

Comment: AWS RDS support has basically gently informed me I have to turn on logging. Sigh. It's going to be a long service request.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no - I'm no longer at that company and don't have access to that AWS ticket anymore! Long story.

Comment: AWS RDS support was generally useless, by the way. They kept telling me I had to turn on logging, even though it was, and I'd uploaded the screenshots showing the same. So I never got past the guy that just reads the book back at you (which often IS the problem,but sometimes it's not). I believe the error had something to do with an external monitoring package setup, via Firehose [sp?] but I couldn't prove it. I did think the product was good so I don't want to mention it by name.

Answer (score 1):

I set up an Amazon RDS instance to log Audit, Error, General, and Slow queries. While these logs were visible in the RDS configuration, I encountered an error when checking CloudWatch.

To resolve this, I followed the RDS service recommendation and changed the log_output parameter to FILE. After making this adjustment, the Slow query log started showing up in CloudWatch. Additionally, I might have set long_query_time to 0 to capture all queries and slow_query_log to 1.

Comment: I upvoted, and I'm glad this fixed your issue, but I don't think this was the cause of the issue I initially reported on. I don't work at the company where we had this issue, so I can't double check, but our log parameters hadn't changed and were set properly (as the logging used to work.) Thanks for the input though, I'm sure it'll help other people running into a similar problem and ending up here via search.